# Flickr Photo ID Regex - Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flickr

Trying to create a regex for flex that accepts a url in the form of:

```
http://www.flickr.com/photos/anguslturner/<photoid>/
```

and extract the following part (the id)

```
http://www.flickr.com/photos/anguslturner/[0]/
```

Searched through Google and can't find anything that works successfully...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not pure RegExp but:

```
var s:String = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/anguslturner";
var username:String = s.split("/photos/")[1];
trace(username);  // returns anguslturner
```

if you want to allow anything after the username:

```
var s:String = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/anguslturner/somethinganythinghere";
var username:String = s.split("/photos/")[1];
trace(username.split("/")[0]); // returns anguslturner
```

Comment: Not regex but still gets the job done for what I need. Thanks!